# Vim Auto Closing Parenthesis Configuration in vimrc

Tags: vim

The title of the question might be similar to some questions here.

But, what I am asking is specific and different:
I have searched some .vimrc files regarding auto closing of parenthesis, as I do not want to install plugin.

So far, this link seems to fit the best:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip153

I tried this mapping below, but it is not working in my vim. It seems to be only working in Perl. Could anyone please let me know what needs to be configured to enable the mapping to work in any vim environment such as normal text?

=============Below is the configuration================
This mapping is not working in my vim editor. Do I miss some package?

```
inoremap { {<CR><BS>}<Esc>ko
```

to be used in conjunction with my autoindent setup:

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

Here is  what i want:

```
{
<cursor here ready for coding>
}
```

Comment: Do you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what it actually did.

Comment: Do you have any trailing whitespace after the mapping? Did you include any comments in this `inoremap` line? Both whitespace and comments would mess this up. 
You also didn't explain what precisely isn't working? Indent is wrong, nothing happens at all, cursor is not ready but moved somewhere else etc.
BTW, I ran vanilla vim with `vim -u NONE --noplugin` and typed all above settings starting with `set nocompatible`, and this mapping seems to work. So please be more specific about how it's behaviour is not correct.

Comment: Thanks all. The last part I wanted does not happen at all. The configuration in my .vimrc has no effects.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
inoremap {} <CR>{<CR>}<Up><CR>
```

After typing {}, it puts them on their own lines with the cursor on a blank line inbetween, like so:

```
void something(){}_
```

becomes

```
void something()
{
    _
}
```

(`_` indicates cursor position)

This assumes you can use the cursor keys in insert mode. If not, you could use the following mapping:

```
inoremap {} <CR>{<CR>}<ESC>O
```

I recommend mapping `{}` over `{` because this makes it easier to use `{` in cases where you actually need the symbol itself. Also, if you want to type `{}` literally, you can just pause for a while between typing the latter character.